# Can't enable File History with external drive

Tags: windows-8.1, file-history

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

(Yes, the *File History* service is already running, so that's not the problem.)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you got the Search Service running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be because the Indexing Service (a.k.a. Windows Search service) was disabled.